# How to read XML data from an API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, read-data

I'm trying to read data from an API in PHP in XML format. I tried

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api...');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', '');
foreach ($xml->PredictionCollection as $collection) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (IntersectionId, LaneNumber, NumberOfBits) VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        $lead->campaign_name
    ));
}     
?>
```

but it returns me errors like:

> Warning: `simplexml_load_file()`:
>   http://api:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
>   in  C:\wamp64\www\readfromanapi.php on line 2
>
> Warning: `simplexml_load_file()`:
>   {"PredictionCollection":[{"IntersectionId":1001,"LocatioCode":"gr_the","TimeStamp
>   in C:\wamp64\www\readfromanapi.php on line 2
>
> Warning: `simplexml_load_file()`: ^
>   in C:\wamp64\www\readfromanapi.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]  [1049] Unknown database 'test''
>   in C:\wamp64\www\readfromanapi.php on line 3 ( ! )
>   PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'
>   in C:\wamp64\www\readfromanapi.php on line 3

Comment: That's not XML, that's JSON.

Comment: Well error 3 says you do not HAVE a database called `test` Did you CREATE a database called `test` before attempting to use it

Comment: where  is JSON @JonStirling?

Comment: @wannabeadev `{"PredictionCollection":[{"IntersectionId":1001,"LocatioCode":"gr_the","TimeStamp...`

Comment: @JonStirling the api is a dynamic site that returns xml tree form... I don't understand what's hapenning...

Comment: _What is JSON_ [See here](https://www.json.org/)

Comment: _site that returns xml tree form_ Well its not returning XML for this call

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you!

Comment: Try using `json_decode()` to convert the JSONString into a PHP Array or Object then the data becomes very usable

Comment: can you please give me an example? If you want to!